# implementing p2p program

Tags: p2p, peer

hi
i have an assignment in school to write a p2p program, and i am trying to understand the idea behind it. we were told to implement two objects FileManager and NameServer:

> A FileManager maintains a set of files. It allows its users to remove\rename existing files and to obtain
>   new files from other FileManagers. On startup, a FileManager F receives as input its list of files and a list
>   of NameServers. Then, F sends its list of filenames and NameServer names to all the NameServers on its
>   NameServers’ list
>
> A NameServer maintains information about which files are stored in each of the known FileManagers.
>   The NameServer also helps to distribute between FileManagers information about other NameServers.

so i am have a hard time understanding the interaction between these two objects. 
do they both run on the same machine? i mean, in p2p each machine function as a server.
i am sorry if the question is a bit unclear as the whole assignment is still a bit unclear to me. can anyone try to help me understand?

Comment: it's realy hard to read, that's not a good school :)

Comment: well the PDF file is 14 pages long, i had to shorten it somehow

Comment: host it @ web and link here, I'll try to take a look later.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BxJd3Cgc6Da8NWI1YjgyMzEtZTA1ZC00Mzg0LWJkNjktNGRjNmQ3ZDA4YWIz&hl=en

Comment: wow, it looks like huge task...

Comment: i know, that's why i only quted one paragraph. but it is not neccessary to read it all, i am just trying to understand the idea of p2p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so i am have a hard time understanding
>   the interaction between these two
>   objects. do they both run on the same
>   machine? i mean, in p2p each machine
>   function as a server.

It means you have two types of nodes on your P2P system, functionally/logically speaking. Some acting as FileManagers and some acting as NameServers. Eventually, a real node may implement both sets of functionalities and act both as a FileManager and NameServer at the same time.

You can see FileManagers and NameServers as services offered by peer instances. Hope this helps.

Comment: so a FileManager can connect to multiple NameServers. should i do it in a different thread for every NameServer?

Comment: You could for a small project, but for a big project it is better to use a library like Netty.

Comment: oh we're not allowed to use non standart libaries. anyway, just to make it a 100% clear - the FileManager connects to a list of NameServer (from a text file) and he HAS to stay connected right? if it is right well then of course i have to run a new thread for each connection. thanks!

Comment: Yes, file manager has to accept incoming connections or contact NameServers itself, and it has to stay connected to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell in your assignment there is no assumption where FileManager and NameServer instances will run. But even if so, this should not influence your solution as you have to use ip addresses and sockets. If you have to communicate with an instance on the same machine just use 127.0.0.1 as address.